# wp_insert_post if page doesn't exist under current page

Tags: wp-insert-post, child-pages, get-children

I am trying to dynamically insert a page/multiple pages as a child under the current page in my template file, using wp_insert_post, however I need to first check if the page title already exists under the current page, and if it doesn't exist then to run the code and create the page(s), but don’t want it to create a duplicate page under the current page if the title already exist under the current page only.

The `get_page_by_title` seems to check if the page exists in the entire sitemap, and if the title exists it will not create the page, but I only need to check if it exists under the current page as there will be pages with the same title under other parent pages

e.g

mywebsite.com/oneparent/child-page-title

mywebsite.com/twoparent/child-page-title

Please see my code below. Is there a better way to use get_page_by_title but to only check the child pages for the current page? Or is there a better method to do this?

```
if (get_page_by_title($episodetitle)==NULL) {
$seasonepisode = array(
    'post_title'    => $episodetitle,
    'post_content'  => 'Some Content',                     
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_parent'   => $post->ID,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'page_template' => 'template-songlist.php'
);

wp_insert_post($seasonepisode);
}
```

**UPDATED WORKING CODE**

```
foreach ($episoderange as $episodelist) {
                        
$episodetitle = 's0' . $season['season_number'] . 'e0' . $episodelist;
    
$currentID = $post->ID;                             
                            
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $currentID, 'post_type' => 'page' ) );               
$seasonepisode = array(
                    'post_title'    => strtolower($episodetitle),
                    'post_content'  => $output_episode['overview'],                     
                    'post_status'   => 'publish',
                    'post_parent'   => $currentID,
                    'post_type'     => 'page',
                    'page_template' => 'template-songlist.php'
           );
                            
$titleslist = array_column($mypages, 'post_title');
                            
//If there are subpages under current page
if (!empty($mypages)){  
    //If the title doesn't already exsist under the current page
    if (!in_array($episodetitle, $titleslist)) {
        wp_insert_post($seasonepisode);
    }                   
} 

//If no subpages exist at all under current page
if (empty($mypages)){
    //Probably dont need this, but just to be safe encase of infinate looping issue
    if (!in_array($episodetitle, $titleslist)) {
        wp_insert_post($seasonepisode);
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();                            
                            
echo '<li><a href="' . strtolower($episodetitle) . '">' . $episodetitle . ' - ' . $output_episode['name'] . '</a></li>';                
                        
}
```

Based on the suggestion by @MMK, I used the get_pages method and simply fetched the existing post_title values as an array and compared current titles with titles from my new pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
);
    
 
$children= new WP_Query( $args );
 $seasonepisode = array(
            'post_title'    => $episodetitle,
            'post_content'  => 'Some Content',                     
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_parent'   => $post->ID,
            'post_type'     => 'page',
            'page_template' => 'template-songlist.php'
           );
if ( $children->have_posts() ){
    while ( $children->have_posts() ) { 
        $children->the_post();
        if(get_the_title() != $episodetitle){
           
            wp_insert_post($seasonepisode);
            exit;
         }
    }//end of while
}else{wp_insert_post($seasonepisode);}//end have posts
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Alternatively

```
$query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));
 
//$assuimg $post is current page
    $children = get_page_children( $post->ID, $all_wp_pages );
$flag=true;
foreach($children as $child){
    if($episodetitle == get_the_title($child))
        $flag=false;
}
if($flag){
    wp_insert_post($seasonepisode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code as suggested in my original post, however pages aren't being created, in your first code, will this only create pages if there are already child pages under the current page?

Comment: yes, I have updated the first code to cater if there are no children. So basically we query children of the current page if there are some children then we start the loop and start matching titles. otherwise, if there are no children then simply a page is being added in else condition.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the first updated code, but get the following errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: parent

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on null

Comment: $parent->have_posts() sorry can you replace this with $children->have_posts()

Comment: @MKK the alternative method throws no errors, but it is creating duplicate pages each time the page is refreshed

Comment: let me check...

Comment: Changing to $children->have_posts() and $child->the_post() just creates an infinite loop, any thoughts?

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: i have updated the code, incorrect  $parent->the_post(); it should have been "$children->the_post();"

Comment: thanks but still creating an infinite loop of pages

Comment: check now, i have added exit statement after insertion. wp_insert_post($seasonepisode);
            exit;

Comment: So this now just creates 1 page and HTML after the exit no longer displays, will try turning it into a function instead unless you have any other ideas

Comment: yeah because you are passing one title $episodetitle. otherwise, it will create multiple pages under the same name.

Comment: I have added my updated code to the OP, the $episodetitle is actually in a foreach statement, so there would be multiple pages which need to be created for each output.

Comment: I have accepted your method as it was very helpful, but had to do something a little different to get it to work how I needed. My working code has been added to the OP

Comment: glad you figured this out.